# Circle , Prove that the locus of the point of intersection of the lines drawn through the points $(a,0)$ and $(-a,0)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Prove that the locus of the point of intersection of the lines drawn through the points $(a,0)$ & $(-a,0)$ which include a constant angle $\theta$ is the Circle
$x^2 +y^2 -a^2 -2ay\cot \theta =0$
OR
$x^2 +y^2 -a^2 +2ay\cot \theta =0$

??

Comment: welcome to math.SE, kindly show your insights to attract more contributors for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Note that $\angle MKB = \theta$.

$MK$ and $KB$ can then be expressed in terms of $a$ and $\theta$.

Use the center-radius form to write the equation of the circle. It should be $$x^2 + (y – a \cot \theta)^2 = (a \csc \theta)^2.$$

Part of the required result follows after simplification of the above.

The other part of the required is the lower half of the circle using $\pi – \theta$ as the constant angle.

Comment: Thank you , you are genius :D :D :D

Comment: @MhmdAbdo Hope that helps and don't forget to accept it as answer by 'ticking' it.

Comment: @MhmdAbdo FYI: By accepting an answer, you have successfully prevented the already-long unanswered list from lengthening.

Comment: @Mick, Could you help me with.this ques. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263164/consider-a-right-angled-triangle-pqr-right-angled-at-p-i-e-angle-qpr-90

Comment: @MhmdAbdo Will do that but just give me some time.