# Consider a right angled $\triangle PQR$ right angled at $P$ i.e ($\angle QPR=90°$) with side $PR=4$ and area$=6$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, rotations

Consider a right angled $\triangle PQR$ right angled at $P$ i.e ($\angle QPR=90°$) with side $PR=4$ and area$=6$. If $\triangle PQR$ is rotated through $360°$ about the side $PR$ , what is the $TSA$ of the resulting solid?

My Attempt:
$$Ar.(\triangle PQR)=6$$
$$\dfrac {1}{2} {PR}\times {PQ}=6$$
$$PQ=3$$.

Again, by Pythagoras Theorem
$$QR=\sqrt {PR^{2} + PQ^{2}}$$
$$QR=5$$.

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Surface area of a cone is $\pi r^2 + \pi rl$ where $r$ is the radius and $l$ is the slant height.

Comment: Did you want to solve this using calculus, or just geometry?

Comment: @Cocomos, Whichever is short and easier.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein Use John Lou's formula. $PQ$ will be your radius since you are rotating about $PR$ and $QR$ will be your slant height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solid will be a cone with radius $PQ=3$ and generator $QR=5$.

Then TSA is given by

$$TSA=\pi \cdot PQ\cdot  QR+\pi PQ^2=15\pi+9\pi=24\pi$$.

[image]

Comment: How do you find that " The solid will be a cone"?

Comment: the axis of rotation is $PR$, right? then you get a cone

Comment: How? Is there any process of calculations??

Comment: @AlbertEinstein: Please, check the pícture. Can you see now?

Comment: Isn't there any hard and fast rule for this?

Comment: @Albert Einstein..just take a piece of triangular cardboard and rotate it very fastly taking any side as its axis of rotation( you can use a stick glued with one of its sides for this purpose). Now, see the surface generated which is a cone.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein Some authors define a cone as the rotation of a triangle. A "right circular cone" is the rotation of a right triangle. (Google "triangle rotation cone"). Also a cone is a "solid of revolution" (another term you can google). So, no there's not a process of calculations, it's a process of applying definition(s).

Comment: @AlbertEinstein `How do you find that "The solid will be a cone"?` That is in fact Euclid's definition of the right circular cone ([Elements Book XI Definition 18](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXI/defXI18.html)): "*When a right triangle with one side of those about the right angle remains fixed is carried round and restored again to the same position from which it began to be moved, the figure so comprehended is a cone.*"

Answer (score 3):

According to the description, the resultant shape is a cone. In which, specific parts have their standard names:-

[image]

PR = vertical height = h; PQ = base radius = r; QR = slant height = L.

---

TSA = (base area) + [curved surface area] = $(\pi r^2) + [\pi \times r \times L]$.

Here is the way to find out why [curved surface area] = $\pi \times r \times L$:-

1) Cut a cone-shaped paper drinking cup along QR.

2) Lay the cut-up object flat.

3) Convince yourself that the flattened object is in the form of a sector of a new circle with the following specs:- radius = L and arc length $= 2 \pi r$.

4) Use the above info to find the central angle of that sector.

5) Find the area of that sector (whose area is exactly that of the curved surface).

Comment: How do we know that we get cone after rotation? Is there any methods/calculation?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein It is a mental visualization process.