# How to calculate plot point?

Tags: physics

[image]

Why is 3 wrong? I know the answer is true for 5, so shouldn't it apply for 5 as well, since both trend negative?

Comment: What is the definition of $x_m$?  Without a definition, I would have thought point $2$ was $+x_m$ and $6$ was $-x_m$.

Comment: I don't know. That's the question in its entirety

Comment: So how did you choose $2$ for the first question instead of $6$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point $4$ is on the axis, so its coordinate is zero.

Comment: Could you help me with.this ques. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263164/consider-a-right-angled-triangle-pqr-right-angled-at-p-i-e-angle-qpr-90