# A question on range of trigonometric functions.

Tags: trigonometry

If $u={\sqrt {a^2\cos^2\alpha + b^2\sin^2\alpha}} + {\sqrt {a^2\sin^2\alpha + b^2\cos^2\alpha}}$, find the difference between the maximum and minimum value of $u^2$.

I tried squaring the expression on both sides but i am ending up with some complex expression, i.e, $a^2 + b^2 + 2\sin \alpha\cos \alpha\sqrt {(a^2-b^2)^2 + (a^2b^2)/(\sin^2 \alpha\cos^2 \alpha)}.$

Please Help.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263431/finding-minimum-of-trigonometric-function/2263448#2263448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S
$$u^2=a^2+b^2+2\sqrt{(a^2\cos^2\alpha+b^2\sin^2\alpha)(b^2\cos^2\alpha+a^2\sin^2\alpha)}\geq$$
$$\geq a^2+b^2+2\sqrt{(ab\cos^2\alpha+ab\sin^2\alpha)^2}=a^2+b^2+2|ab|=(|a|+|b|)^2.$$
The equality occurs when $$(a\cos\alpha,b\sin\alpha)||(b\cos\alpha,a\sin\alpha),$$
which says that $(|a|+|b|)^2$ is a minimal value.

Comment: What Is C-S? Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality